# Is it possible to separate Pi from Eulers constant with rational constants?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, pi

1. $\pi^2 \cdot e^2 \sim \frac{10000}{137}$, is quite accurate, although I have no idea what this "fine structure constant" $\frac{1}{137}$  from physics really is.
2. For any prime numbers $p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4$,  $(p_1 * p_2 * p_3 * p_4)^9$  has always exactly $10000$ divisors  and the powers of $2$ do relate to the powers of $10$ in some way dependent of their divisors, which also seems to relate in some form to $\pi$.

So my question is, is it possible to separate $\pi$, from $e$ in the first equation without using recursions or irrational numbers and how does $\pi$ relate to the $2^{10} = 1024, 10^3 = 1000$  coincidence?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. Although if your question is whether you can express $e$ as a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ evaluated at $\pi$, meaning $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically dependant, then, unfortunately, I don't think anyone can answer that as that is still an open problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not answer the question but relates the approximation in the question to another one.

Since $137\pi^2e^2 \approx 9991$, the accuracy of the following approximation is better.

$$\pi^2e^2 \approx \frac{100^2-3^2}{137}$$

Now if we bother to write $$\frac{100^2-3^2}{\pi^2e^2} \approx 136.999899991$$
this is closer to an integer than the nice

$$e^\pi-\pi \approx 19.999099979$$

And the ratio of the distance of both expressions from an integer is close to yet another integer.

$$\frac{e^\pi-\pi-20}{\frac{100^2-3^2}{\pi^2e^2}-137} \approx 9$$

I believe that the following expression is also worth mentioning.
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\approx137.035999 \approx \frac{34259}{250}=5^3+12+\frac{3^2}{2·5^3}=5^3+\frac{5^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+5^{-2}-\frac{5^{-3}}{2}$$

In other words, the polynomial $(2n+1)^3+3n^2$ takes the value $137$ for $n=2$. Equivalently, $(4n+1)^3+3(2n)^2$ gives $137$ for $n=1$. Here is an illustration of $137$ as a three-dimensional shape.

[image: 137 as a 3D shape]

Only the faces seen have additional cubes, shown in red. Those extra cubes could be halved and shared among the seen and unseen faces for another symmetry.

Regarding the $2^{10} \approx 10^3$, since $10=2·5$ we can simplify it down a bit to the following.

$$2^{10} \approx 10^3 = 2^35^3$$
$$2^7 \approx 5^3$$

---

Update

A simpler fourth power $(9^4)$ yields a better approximation:
$$\pi \approx \frac{27}{e\sqrt{10}} \approx 3.1410097$$

compared to
$$\pi \approx \frac{100}{e\sqrt{137}} \approx 3.143006$$

However, from your approximation the following almost-integer is obtained.

$\frac{10^4}{137\pi^2e^2} \approx 1.0009000 $

This happens to match the gap in $e^\pi-\pi$, so combining both gives

$$e^\pi-\pi+\frac{10^4}{137\pi^2e^2} \approx 21.000000058$$

Comment: $3*73*137=30003$  seems very special as well, as $3*7*11*13=3003$ is conjectured to be the only number that appears 8 times in pascal's triangle, although it can be argued if 969 isn't appear more often all in all.

Comment: No idea, and $3003 \neq 30003$. Related to your original question, you can also write
$\pi \approx (10e^{8})^\frac{1}{9}$ from an approximation by D. Ehlke found at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html, probably not what you want.

Comment: Just want to understand Pi on the line of primes when it's only allowed to use addition/substraction and some transform rules maybe..

Comment: Gilbreath's conjecture seems to be related to it also, when instead of using the absolute values of differences, only the normal values of differences are used, but each time if the difference would be negative, instead of using it' negative value or the absolute value, it get's flipped orthogonally and used as a normal value

Comment: and the same way on the orthogonally flipped side, if a difference gets negative, it get's flipped back instead and so on. The cyclical pattern from those flipping points is maybe Pi, not sure actually if this is not the easy way to see the Riemann's Zeta function and the conjecture, without using any complex numbers and frictions and roots and such.

Comment: Maybe you would like to study some posts by Mats Granvik, such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41868/is-this-a-relation-between-the-riemann-zeta-function-and-the-prime-zeta-function?

Comment: Or this one at MathOverflow (different site, for professional mathematicians)
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16991/what-are-the-connections-between-pi-and-prime-numbers

Comment: @Eugen, there is $8*137 = 1096 = 4(2^{10}-10^3)+10^3$, FWIW. 8 is the number of octants, to place the figure above -rotated- and get the symmetry of a cube.

Comment: 3003 appears in 
$$\pi \approx \frac{650960-\frac{1}{90}}{3·23·3003}$$
This approximation comes from a series:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=24%21+sum+Pochhammer%28k%2B1%2C5%29%2FPochhammer%284k%2B1%2C23%29+for+k%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: So I get it, I can use Pi for primality testings, if I devide any composite number by Pi, I will find the prime factors of it at some decimal positions of the resulted value, the efficiency of this method might need a lot of tweakening, but in general it must work for any natural numbers, still it isn't all clear why it is this way for this number.

Comment: What? How do you intend to find the prime factors? Can you write an example of that?