# How can one decide between structure or coincidence regarding the fine structure constant?

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, diophantine-approximation

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3975866/is-it-possible-to-seperate-pi-from-eulers-constant-with-rational-constants) originates the following observations about the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant), $\alpha$.

Measurements of $\alpha^{-1}$ yield values slightly smaller than $137.036$, and a good rational fit for all of them is $\frac{34259}{250}$. The choice of $250$ does not seem to be decimally biased, because one can multiply any value close to $137.035999$ for all integers up to say $300$ and $250$ emerges as a proper denominator more clearly than $113$ for $\pi$.

One of the alternative approximate expressions for $\alpha^{-1}$ is $$5^3+\frac{5^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+5^{-2}-\frac{5^{-3}}{2}$$ After some easy manipulation, this can be written as $$\frac{1}{2^3}(10^3+2^3·3(1+\frac{3}{10^3}))$$

I would like to learn how to decide between structure or coincidence, based on data. For instance, how should one compare the complexities of the approximate value of the constant ($137.036$) and the above expression that suggests some internal structure?

An equivalent way to see $137$ (only the integer part of $\alpha^{-1}$) is the following image, corresponding to the polynomial $(4n+1)^3+3(2n)^2$ at $n=1$, or $(2n+1)^3+3n^2$ at $n=2$.

[image: 137 as a 3D shape]

I would classify this as a figurate number, as it is the sum of related (by $n$) figurate numbers (even squares and related cubes). But how can the *structureness* of this representation be evaluated?

---

Working with spheres instead of cubes, the correction $.036$ may be obtained from the normalized volume of a sphere of radius $5$ with $24·5^6$ spheres of radius $\frac{1}{25}$ centered on its surface, according to the following volume integral

$$\frac{4}{3}\alpha^{-1} \approx  \frac{4}{3}\times137.036 = \int_{-10}^{0} (5^2 - (x + 5)^2) dx $$

$$+ 24·5^6 \left( \int_{-\frac{1}{10·25^2}}^{\frac{1}{25}} \left(\frac{1}{25^2} - x^2\right) dx - \int_{-\frac{1}{10·25^2}}^{0} \left(5^2 - (x + 5)^2\right) dx\right)$$

Comment: Perhaps you like to read also http://www.quanten.de/forum/showthread.php5?t=2355&page=9 . This is a forum in german language, but the core information are cites in english language (references to Han de Vries). I don't understand much from the entire field of problem, but it looks like good read, good data and possibly constructive ideas about a "structure" in the explanation for the data.

Comment: Just in case you've not already seen this: http://www.chip-architect.com/news/2004_10_04_The_Electro_Magnetic_coupling_constant.html (Hans de Vries' own blog)

Comment: Thank you, @GottfriedHelms